# accessing array of objects in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to show datas from database. But the datas are showing as they appear in my database.

like this--

```
{"caption":"hello","link":"","medias":["66daf3ea.jpg"],"advance":"null"}
{"caption":"hi","link":"","medias":null,"advance":"null"}
{"caption":"nice","link":"https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=U10nBuERNIA&list=RDd-DwZmU1-pQ&index=24","medias":null,"advance":"null"}
```

I just want to show the "caption"

In my view file. the code is--

```
<?php
    foreach (json_decode($h->result())->data as $row) {
        if ($row->social_network == 'twitter' ) {
            echo $row->caption ;
        }
      }
    ?>
```

my controller code is--

```
public function fb_posts()
{
    $this->load->database();  
    $this->load->model('select');  
    $data['h']=$this->select->select();  
    $this->load->view('fb_posts', $data);  
}
```

How do I process the data and show them separately?

If I use json_decode it's showing **" json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given"**

[image: database image]

Comment: Have you ever read the `codeigniter select` manual?

Comment: I am new to codeigniter. I managed to solve this in laravel by using "json_decode" . But In codeIgniter it's not working

Comment: Why wouldn't json_decode work in CI? What code did you use? Do you get an error? If so, what does it say?

Comment: I have updated the question. the error is-- json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: Assuming `$row->caption` contains your JSON you'd need to `json_decode($row->caption)`

Comment: What did you mean by "I just want to show the caption"? Do you want to only show the `caption`  field in view? If so, you just need to select the column from the database.

Comment: Undefined property: stdClass::$caption-- now showing this @brombeer

Comment: @JunPan "caption","link","media" are all in same column called "data"

Comment: I have uploaded an image. The "data"  field is selected on the image

Comment: but how to display them separately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the pic you post, I can see the `caption` is stored in a JSON string. So, in order to use the caption field, you need to decode the `data` first.

Check out the code below:

```
<?php
     foreach ($h->result() as $row) {
        if ($row->social_network == 'twitter') {
            $data = json_decode($row->data);
            echo $data->caption;
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Trying to get property 'data' of non-object--- showing on foreach loop

Comment: I have changed the code. now its working